# Aligning issue for web design html/css. fiddle included.

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am attempting to design a responsive layout in which there is an image and a paragraph side by side and the image is vertically aligned with the text (the paragraph height changes with adjustments to the browser width).

Here is my currant code,
http://jsfiddle.net/xSrpt/

I have tried using

```
    vertical-align:middle;
```

and

```
    vertical-align:central;
```

on the parent div (#intro) and have not been able to get anywhere with it. 
I feel like this should be an easy fix and i am missing something but hopefully you guys can help.

please include a working fiddle with your answer.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to add a comment to above answer ( rep too low ).
It is unnecessary to convert the div into table.

All you have to do is applying vertical-align:middle to **child element** and not the parent.

```
#intro > * { vertical-align:middle }
```

Here's your forked fiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/UBD6S/

much simpler solution.

Answer (score 1):

try add to its parent - `display:table-cell;`

edit:

you need to make the div "act" like a table, as below:

```
CSS:
#intro{
   display:table; /** table **/
    width:90%;
    background-color: #999;
    padding:5%;
}
#pic{
    height:100%;
    width:80px;
    background:black;
    display:table-cell; /** table-cell **/
    vertical-align:middle;
}
#your_pic {
    width:80px;
    height:80px;
    background:#fff;
}
#p{
    display:inline-block;
    width:80%;
}

HTML:
<div id="intro">
    <div id="pic"><div id="your_pic"></div></div>
<p id="p">text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text </p>
</div>
```